# how to save input value of text form field as soon as type completed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

i have a text form field that user enter to it a code that sent to it and i must decide if input code is true or false but can not save value of text form field i have a button like it

```
 GestureDetector(
        onTap: ()  {
          _formKey.currentState.save();
          setState(() {
            inputcode=key.getter("sms");
            print(inputcode);
            print(verifycode);
          });
        },

        child: inputcode==verifycode?send:
        VirtualBotton("please enter correct code","ok",40.0,10.0,width: 120.0,),
      )
```

but i must press two times button for done this work
in this code when i enter correct code first run virtual Button class and second times that i press button run correct code       how to run on tap before build child in button this is text form field

```
TextFormField(
    inputFormatters: [
      new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(30),
    ],

    onSaved: (value) {
      key.setter(id, value);


    },
    textAlign: alignment == null ? TextAlign.right : alignment,
    maxLines: maxlines==null?1:maxlines,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14,

    ),
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    controller: ctrl,

    validator: (String value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return "";
      }
      return null;
    },

    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        hintText: _hint,
        errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(

            color: hintconlor == null ? Colors.grey : hintconlor,
            fontSize: hintsize == null ? 13 : hintsize)),
  ),
);
```

Comment: see You have `controller: ctrl,` in your code, as @mikhail-ponkin said, You should use that.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `TextEditingController` and listen to controller changes. [Here are docs with examples](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes)

Comment: note i have text form field not text field and it not onChanged method

Comment: @mohammadshabani I've removed part with `onChanged`. `TextEditingController` will work